# Replace regular expression with \t in Notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, special-characters, notepad++

simple example in Notepad++ using RegEx replace
search for: anything
replace with (wanted): **\test**

1. guess for regex replace string: **\test**
   results in: **`tab`est**, so the \t is interpreted as a `tab`
2. guess for regex replace string: **\\test**
   results in: **\ `tab`est**, so the first \ is interpreted as a \, the \t is interpreted as a `tab`
3. guess for regex replace string: **\ test** (`space`in between \ and test)
   results in: **\ test** (`space`in between \ and test)

How can I do this to get \test as the result? Are there any group or end of command characters for the replace string? Or an empty character that I can add after the \?

Thanks,
Axel

Comment: Apparently, no matter how many `\ ` we put, it will take them literally except for the one before `t`. Sounds like a bug - report it.

Comment: It took some effort to key in that backslash within back-ticks - I cheated with a space after backslash. Sounds like the bug is here in SO too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an [open issue with notepad++](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2954483&group_id=95717&atid=612382).

Answer (score 1):

How about replacing with `\\test`? Usually `\` must be escaped with `\`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't format my question correctly. Changed it now. Of course I tried that, result as now seen above.

Comment: Ok, just tried it myself in Notepad++ - works in extended mode, but not with regular expressions. weird...

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with \r and \n either. My guess - as Jens said - would be that this is a bug in Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

Try 3 backslashes, this kind of thing often works in other tools/languages.

Answer (score 0):

`\\test` should do the trick. Try it and let me know.

Comment: And you, did you try it?

Comment: no, I did not try it. \\test does the trick, my previous answer ( \\\[t]est ) was wrong.